# login from window nt in a local mechain failed

Tags: c#

Hello any body helpme in this problem
 iam created a c# application in windows xp system under administatar account.
when iam running this it is working well and accesing sqldatabase.
Now the problem is  iam created one account uder groups as a guest account.
the account name is TRMS Accont and now iam login from this account and run the already created c# application under admin account.First it is logined to application
  now it is showing this kind of error 
Login failed for user 'LENOVO\TRMS Account.
  when iam debugging the error is
 Warning    1   Could not read state file "obj\Debug\ResolveAssemblyReference.cache". Access to the path 'D:\aug\TRMSFrontEnd\Transaction\obj\Debug\ResolveAssemblyReference.cache' is denied.  Transaction
Warning 2   Could not read state file "obj\Debug\Transaction.csproj.GenerateResource.Cache". Access to the path 'D:\aug\TRMSFrontEnd\Transaction\obj\Debug\Transaction.csproj.GenerateResource.Cache' is denied.    Transaction
Warning 3   Could not write state file "obj\Debug\Transaction.csproj.GenerateResource.Cache". Access to the path 'D:\aug\TRMSFrontEnd\Transaction\obj\Debug\Transaction.csproj.GenerateResource.Cache' is denied.   Transaction
Error   4   Could not write lines to file "obj\Debug\Transaction.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt". Access to the path 'D:\aug\TRMSFrontEnd\Transaction\obj\Debug\Transaction.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt' is denied.    Transaction

Answer (score 1):

Those errors clearly show that you don't have sufficient privileges to access specific files .
Try to Run the program as Administrator . See [Run As Administrator](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305780)